# Why I am not able to get token from cookies?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cookies

When User login,app send request to backend / nextjs. Next js set cookies via res.Header(...) and then send respond back to front-end. And there I am not able to get cookies-token, but this token I can see in application/Cookies.

here is backend code

```
try {

  const email = req.body.email
  const password = req.body.password
  
  const user = await User.findOne({ email })

  if(!user) {
    throw new Error(`User doesn't exist!`)
  }

  // compare password
  const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
  if(!validPassword) {
    throw new Error('Invalid password!')
  }

  const signData = {
    userId: user._id,
    name: user.name,
    email: user.email,
    admin: user.isAdmin
  }
 
  const token = jwt.sign( signData, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
      expiresIn: '4h',
    });

    res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', `token=${token}; HttpOnly; Max-Age=${60 * 60 * 24 * 1}; Path=/login`);

    return res.status(201).json({
      success: true,
      message: 'Welcome back',
    });


    
  } catch (error) {
     console.log(error)
     res.status(500).send({
      success: false,
      message: error.message
     })
  }
```

and here is front-end

```
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';

try {
      
      const res = await axios.post('/api/user/login', data, config)
      console.log(res.data)
      
      toast.success(res.data.message)

      const token = Cookies.get('token');
      console.log('token', token);  // token undefined

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      toast.error(error.response.data.message)
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple. the httponly cookies are not accessible in the client javascript. and that is completely expected. httponly has been created this way to prevent  XSS attacks.

###### [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies) says:

> A cookie with the HttpOnly attribute is inaccessible to the JavaScript Document.cookie API; it's only sent to the server. For example, cookies that persist in server-side sessions don't need to be available to JavaScript and should have the HttpOnly attribute. This precaution helps mitigate cross-site scripting (XSS) attacks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to use the cookies() function from next js to read the incoming HTTP res headers.
This only happens in the server component though, but you could just pass it down to a client component

```
import {cookies} from 'next/headers'

export default async function Page() {
 console.log(cookies().getAll());
 return (

 )
}
```